# Как открыть файл в python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется текстовый файл.
Пытаюсь набрать...

```
open('mbox-short.txt')
```

При исполнении программы выдаёт ошибку:

```
No such file or directory.
```

Пробовал писать полностью путь:

`open('C:\Users\ZTL\Desktop\Python-write\Py4inf\list\mbox-short.txt')`

Ошибка - `unicode error - codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При указании полного пути, надо либо экранировать обратные слеши (`'C:\\Users\\...`),
либо использовать сырые строки (raw strings) - добавлять `r` перед открывающей кавычкой `r'C:\Users\...'`.